# in wordpress 3.1 how to have several Wysiwyg boxes on a Custom Post Type?

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, wysiwyg

Is there a way in Wordpress 3.1 either using a plugin or a bit of code to have several TinyMCE/ wysiwyg instances on a Custom Post Type admin page?

Answer (score 1):

[Take a look at this discussion](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/436/is-there-a-way-to-get-n-number-of-wysiwyg-editors-in-a-custom-post-type)

Answer (score 0):

I worked this out eventually - simplest way is to use the cool plugin Custom Field Template, which allows several wysiwygs. It generates a custom field for you and you can applly it to different post types (pages, posts and custom ones!). Go me!